# OpenCV 1.0: cvCreateFileCapture Always Returns Null under Fedora 11

Tags: linux, opencv

I'm attempting to open a video file using openCV 1.0's highgui.cvCreateFileCapture(path) function on a Fedora 11 system. Unfortunately, this function is always returning null. I've attempted to use it on a few different video formats, and I've even taken the steps recommend on the openCV wiki (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs) to use mencoder to transcode to RAWI420 as follows:

```
$ mencoder in.avi -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -o out.avi
```

This has seemed to have no effect, so I'm a bit stuck. No error is produced, null (or, since I'm using the python wrapper, None) is returned. I have ffmpeg, ffmpeg-devel and ffmpeg-libs installed so I think I should have appropriate codec support. Does anyone know how this could be resolved, or in lieu of a resolution, what steps could be taken to debug the issue?

Comment: Please don't use this dinosaur.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem on Ubuntu 10.10, and for me it was a problem with the libraries. I couldn't find out which library was the one that was missing, but I discovered that executing the installation scripts for Openframeworks before compiling OpenCV worked!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you installed OpenCV. OpenCV can use one of many different engines for reading video files, including ffmpeg, gstreamer, and xine (I believe). Make sure that your installation is indeed using ffmpeg as the engine. The easiest way I can think of to do this is by calling "ldd programname" and seeing if ffmpeg is listed as one of the dependencies. Furthermore, you need to make sure that the engine is capable of processing your video codec.

OpenCV is unfortunately very quiet about what causes errors. Returning NULL could mean, "unable to handle codec", and it could mean, "access denied". You could run your process through strace and see what the system calls are returning as one possible option. Worst case scenario, you'll need to use a debugger and walk through the code as you call cvCreateFileCapture. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is already on version 2.x

Do yourself a favour and update it to version 2.1 (at least)